# Encoding Space Character in URL Hash

Tags: url, browser, query-string, spaces, url-encoding

**How the Space Character is handled (encoded) in the URL after the # sign.**

I've the URL:

```
http://example.com/page.html#BookMark location
```

When I use `%20` or `+` that is used to escape the space character in Query String (the string in URL after `?`), I got the URL be double espaced by the browser -The behavior that doesn't happen when dealing with Query String-, example:

When I enter:

```
http://example.com/page.html#BookMark%20location
```

I got the browser try requesting this URL instead:

```
http://example.com/page.html#BookMark%2520location
```

Comment: Where exactly is this entered? If in the browser address bar, just use a space.

Comment: A customer requirement to enter the URL where?

Comment: mm, In `IFRAME`. I Know the spaces will never harm him, but I want find a solution for it.